# "{controller}/{action}/{id}" do not pass the parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my StudenntController I hvae a method

```
public ActionResult ClassStudents(int? classRoomId)
{   
    var students = st.GetAll().Where(s => s.ClassRoomID == classRoomId);

    ViewBag.ClassRoomTitle = clr.GetAll().Where(c=>c.ClassRoomID == classRoomId).Single().ClassRoomTitle;

    return View(students);
}
```

when i enter localhostxxxx/Student/ClassStudent/1
the parameter classRoomId is null and i got a error: Sequence contains no elements
I wonder why url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" do not pass the parameter?

Comment: How did you configure route table?

Comment: Can you provide your route config code? If you use default config, then the parameter must be id instead of classRoomId

Answer (score 2):

you can set id paramter  in routing .

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "ClassStudents", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

parameter should match the route values

```
public ActionResult ClassStudents(int id)
{
     // Your code here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the route to work, the parameter must be named `id`. In your code, the parameter is named `classRoomId`. Change your method signature to:

```
public ActionResult ClassStudents(int? id)
{
     // Your code here
}
```

If you really want to name the parameter `classRoomID` then you would need to create a custom route.